# C++ Novice, Putting a string into a struct

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

This is my first post and am a beginner in C++. I am trying to write a simple program in C++ to display a form which collects data and then puts some data into a struct. This struct shall then hold an array of structs. This is all a learning step so I am open to criticism. I have the form up and running but I would also like to be able to see what is in my struct at any given time.

Here is my Struct

```
struct student
{
    char firstName[30];
    char secondName[30];
    char addr1[30];
    char addr2[30];
    char postcode[30];
    int testScore;
    int average;
};
```

And here is the snippet code which I am struggling with.

```
int gwtstat = 0; /* Get Window Status from "getwindowtext" function*/
student submit;

gwtstat = GetWindowText(firstName, &submit.firstName[0], 30),
gwtstat = GetWindowText(secondName, &submit.secondName[0], 30);

//gwtstat = GetWindowText(addrLine1, &addrLine1Txt[0], 30);
//gwtstat = GetWindowText(addrLine2, &addrLine2Txt[0], 30);
//gwtstat = GetWindowText(addrLine3, &addrLine3Txt[0], 30);
//gwtstat = GetWindowText(postcode, &postcodeTxt[0], 30);
//gwtstat = GetWindowText(landlineNumber, &landlineTxt[0], 30);
//gwtstat = GetWindowText(mobileNumber, &mobileTxt[0], 30);

// This is what I am having problems with
::MessageBox(hwnd, submit.firstName submit.secondName, "Submitted Structure", MB_OK);
//cout << "First Name " << firstNameTxt << endl; /* Doesnt work in a Win32 application?*/
```

Is there a direct way of getting the TextFields into the struct directly and also observing the data that has been placed into my struct in some sort of debug log or message box?

Apologies if the question is a bit indirect as I am not entirely sure what the best way to accomplish this is or even if it is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx).

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Put a break point and use the debugger.

Comment: Why not use strings instead of fixed length character arrays?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Strings in C?

Comment: I have read the documentation of MessageBox and tried to split my two struct elements of submit.firstName and submit.secondName over two lines using a carriage return "\r" but this doesnt seem to work.  The example given in the MessageBox Documentation only refers to strings as far as I could see.  I will have a read of OutputDebugString.I have also put a breakpoint in but I would rather just have a console type output which is dumped everytime the program runs through that portion of code.

Comment: I also tried to use strings in my struct but the were not scoped so I guess I did not have the correct library included.  However I am learning so I will refactor for strings if I am able to.  I did read a similar post that said about putting each struct element into a buffer and using sprintf but I was hoping there may have been a more direct approach without creating another buffer.

Comment: @nicomp Nope, but this is C++. See the title, and the body, and `::MessageBox`. I corrected the erroneous tag.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Aha, you fixed the tag. It's all good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a better way to get info out of a form and into your struct. For displaying values try:

```
char name[100];
sprintf_s(name, 100, "%s %s", submit.firstName, submit.secondName);
::MessageBox(hwnd, name, "Submitted Structure", MB_OK);
```

Also,  you don't really need the [0] in your GetWindowText() calls. The pointer will point to the first character of the string.

Edit: As mentioned the & is also unnecessary since `submit.firstName` behaves like `&submit.firstName[0]`.

Comment: You might want to explicitly mention that you also don't need the '&', i.e. that `submit.firstName` behaves like `&submit.firstName[0]`.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c++]. There is no reason to invent arbitrary array bounds, nor is there a reason to use unsafe calls like `sprint` (which, to my knowledge, doesn't exist). Use an `istringstream` instead, and dump the information using `OutputDebugString`. No need for intrusive message-box style 'debugging'.

Comment: I've edited the above to include the suggestion about the &. Been doing too much C# and overlooked that. @linspectable I agree the code should be using more modern C++, including using Unicode aware types rather than char arrays. I'll edit my response to use sprintf_s().

Comment: @DAM Thankyou for the insight, this is the kind of help I was looking for.  I will try the sprintf_s approach as well as the istringstream.